# Vue.js and Firestore update only the variables that are not equal to empty string

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, object, google-cloud-firestore

update only the variables that are not equal to empty string

```
    const state = reactive({
      birthNumber: '',
      phoneNumber: '',
      DoctorName: '',
      DoctorPhone: '',
    })
```

```
      db.collection(state.user.uid).doc("Personal_Records").update({
        birthNumber: state.birthNumber,
        phoneNumber: state.phoneNumber,
        DoctorName: state.DoctorName,
        DoctorPhone: state.DoctorPhone
      })
```

I only need to update the variables that will change. Firestore still changes them with an empty string.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

When using Firestore `update()` method, you don't need to pass all the values of your document. Just passing the new changed values will be enough as the `update()` method will change just this field in your Firestore document. so you need to check if your fields have values from your app and pass them to the `update()` method accordingly. Read more about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)

Answer (score 0):

You an can build an object the contains only fields to update, and pass that to `update()`.  You determine which properties to set on that object.

```
const update = {}
if (shouldUpdateBirthNumber} {
    update.birthNumber = state.birthNumber
}
// repeat for each optional field to update

db.collection(state.user.uid).doc("Personal_Records").update(update);
```